# gpg: error reading symlink '/proc/curproc/file': No such file or directory

Tags: gnupg, gpg-agent

Every time I sign something, it display the next error:

```sh
➜  ~ echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
gpg: error reading symlink '/proc/curproc/file': No such file or directory
gpg: using "8D5850D90161A3C94B9985084F40757FE4E85476" as default secret key for signing
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

test
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

iHUEARYKAB0WIQSNWFDZAWGjyUuZhQhPQHV/5OhUdgUCYXWvIwAKCRBPQHV/5OhU
dgTpAQCvVt1M/nu5lIZ92fDO1FvNG1j/m3jLwuifaat4SqOVbgD+I2+Qu54blco6
4YXzVYyr0xpSJYzh9a2m0WmrG08v4AI=
=LZsF
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

My `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` seems in order and it's working properly.

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [this bugreport](https://dev.gnupg.org/T5656), the error message seems to be a harmless bug introduced in version 2.3.3 on macOS. The report states it can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

The bug is now solved with 2.3.3_1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).